# PHP Strict Standards: Non-static method Fatal::dbError()

Tags: php, exception, methods, standards, strict

I am troubleshooting an error in PHP and I don't know how to resolve it. I don't have any PHP knowledge.

Here is the code:

```
function _act($sql) {
   if (!$this->_link) {
      Fatal::internalError('Tried to make database query before connection.');
   }

   $r = mysql_query($sql, $this->_link);

   if ($r === false) {
      Fatal::dbError($sql, "Database query failed", mysql_error());
   }
   return $r;
 }
```

In the error log I get the following:

> [24-Jan-2013 13:25:38 America/Denver] PHP Strict Standards: Non-static method Fatal::dbError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home1/flcclear/public_html/Library/classes/Query.php on line 91

I have tried to make it an object call with `$r->mysql_error();` but this caused a different error. I am not trying to rewrite this code, just trying to correct the errors for an elementary/middle school which equals no money, volunteer time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but the error message is referring to the "Fatal::dbError" and not to "mysql_error".

Comment: Don't use the `mysql`-extension anymore. Read http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Comment: @KingCrunch the question is not about what "use"
the question is about a failure, add comments to your response may be useful, but give way first so that he can solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

make Fatal::internalError,Fata::dbError (also other methods you are using like "Fatal::methodName") static

example :

```
class Fatal
{
    public static dbError($sql,$message){
    //method body
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

but the error message is referring to the `Fatal::dbError` and not to `mysql_error`.

`Fatal::dbError` is a class designed for you? Try this:

```
Class Fatal{
  ...
  static public dbError(...){...}
  ...
}
```